# How to match elements from data frame with values from an array in R?

Tags: r, arrays, dataframe, merge, left-join

I want to match elements from `df1` with values from an `array1`.

```
df1 <- (c('A','S','E','E','V','G','H','P','K','L','W','N','P','A','A','S','E','N','M','Y','S','G','D','R','H'))


array1

     1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11  12   13  14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25
A 0.15 0.00 0.10 0.10 0.05 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00
C 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
D 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.10 0.00 0.05 0.05 0.00 0.0 0.10 0.0 0.00 0.25 0.10 0.20 0.10 0.00 0.15 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.05
E 0.05 0.10 0.05 0.05 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.10 0.10 0.20 0.00 0.0 0.05 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.10 0.00 0.20 0.10 0.05 0.15 0.10 0.10
F 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.0 0.05 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
G 0.00 0.00 0.10 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00
H 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
I 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.2 0.05 0.1 0.05 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
K 0.00 0.10 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.10 0.00 0.05
L 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.10 0.00 0.10 0.00 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.2 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00
M 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
N 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00
P 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.05 0.00 0.10 0.10 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.10 0.00 0.05 0.00
Q 0.00 0.05 0.05 0.00 0.10 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.0 0.00 0.1 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05
R 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.05 0.15 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
S 0.10 0.10 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.15 0.10 0.20 0.05 0.10 0.10 0.05 0.00 0.05 0.05 0.10
T 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.05 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.00
V 0.05 0.05 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.05 0.00 0.10 0.2 0.15 0.0 0.15 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
W 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
Y 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.10 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
```

The expected outcome can be a list or a df:

0.15, 0.10, 0.05, 0.05, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.10, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.10, 0.05, 0.05, 0.00, 0.00, 0.05, 0.05, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00

This is what I have tried:

```
res <- left_join(df1, array1, by = array1[[y]])
view(res)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use matrix subsetting on `array1` :

```
array1[cbind(match(df1, rownames(array1)), 1:ncol(array1))]

#[1] 0.15 0.10 0.05 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.10 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
#[14] 0.00 0.00 0.10 0.05 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.00
```

`match(df1, rownames(array1))` creates a row number to subset based on values in `df1`.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to scale it up. I added more rows for 'df1'.  I used this: 'array1[cbind(lapply(df1, FUN = array1), simplify = "array", 1:ncol(array1))]' but it doesn't seem to work. I tried with do.call(combn() too, with no luck. Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't understand why you would do `lapply(df1, FUN = array1)`. `FUN` is for function. `array1` is not function. Better to ask it as a new question instead of extending it.